# Can I change US dollars to Thai baht in Thoeng, Chiang Rai, Thailand - not in a bank?

Tags: thailand, exchange

I crossed the border from Laos to Thailand a couple of days ago and now I'm staying in a cheap hotel in Thoeng in Chiang Rai Province with not quite enough baht left for the rent. But I do have some unused USD left.

Since I was last in Thailand, ATM fees have skyrocketed to a whopping 220 baht, which is more than a night's rent! I've read the fee is lower at AEON ATM's in Tesco Lotus shops, but there's not one in Thoeng.

I recall changing money in banks in Thailand is expensive and difficult. So I'd like to avoid that too.

Is there an actual money changer in Thoeng?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been living in Thailand for the past couple years, and have exchanged money for work and travel at quite a few banks - I've never had problems, though.  If you go to a bank, make sure you bring your passport, and prepare to wait in line for a bit.  If possible go early to avoid lunch break and post-lunch food coma.
I'm not sure about any money changers in Thoeng, however I would imagine any travel agency or larger hotel could point you in the right direction.  If you go that route, check the exchange rate first, I would recommend the [kasikorn bank website](https://www.kasikornbank.com/en/International-Business)
Good luck :)